# Default timeouts for Spring 5 Webclient

Tags: spring, netty, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I'm just looking to confirm the default timeouts that are set for the Spring 5 `WebClient`, which uses the `ReactorClientHttpConnector`.

From my digging so far, it seems:

- Connect timeout is set to 30 secs (`io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelConfig.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT`)
- There doesn't, by default, appear to be a read timeout set.

Is this correct? I'm somewhat surprised this isn't something that can be found via a quick google or scan of the docs (unless I've missed something).